# Minimization of Quasiconcave Function

Tags: discrete-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a function given below:

$f(x,y) = \log_2(1 - xe^y + c + ax + axe^y)$

I was hoping to find $(x,y)$ that minimizes this function. The constraints are $0 < x <1$ and $y > 0$. Here, both $x$ and $y$ are discrete. I wasn't sure if the function is convex or not. So, I tried checking and I think the function is $quasiconcave$. How can I find $(x,y)$ in this case such that it minimizes $f$?

Comment: whether the problem has a solution will depend on the value of $a$. Is $a<1$?

Comment: yes, $a < 1$. Does it have a solution?

Comment: Yes, it does if $x$ and $y$ are continuous. I am not sure, though, what values you are allowed to give to $x$ and $y$ since you mention that they take discrete values.

Comment: x can be between $0$ and $1$ and y can be greater than $0$

Comment: Do you mean $x\in[0,1]$ and $y\geq 0$ (you have strict inequalities in the question). But, then, the problem is not discrete.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are correct. $x \in (0,1)$ and $y \geq 0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105163/discussion-between-pegasus-and-shahnewaz).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Notice that $\log_2$ is a strictly increasing function. The same holds for $x\mapsto x+c$.

Comment: Are you implying that the $(x,y)$ that minimizes $f$ is a corner solution? As $\log_2$ is a strictly increasing function, the solution would be the starting point?

Comment: Well... it should be the solution that minimizes the argument. How does the expression "inside" the $\log_2$ behave?

Comment: I think the expression inside the $\log_2$ is not strictly increasing. It increases and then decrease

Comment: As a function of $x$ or of $y$? Try to factor out what you can.